# advanced boot options ubuntu 14.04 dvd

Tags: 14.04, dvd, livedvd

I have been trying to access the advanced menu when booting from a ubuntu 14.04.1 32 bit dvd. I have tried f6, f12, all the f's actually, and I cant stop it from loading the graphical menu where you choose to try live or install. The md5 sum for the iso is right. Is there any reason I wouldn't be able to get to the advanced options?

EDIT: I should also mention that I have tries other keys, like letters, arrows, etc., and I have done all this when the little logo was at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I would try pressing any other key that's not one of the f* keys when the small logo appears at the bottom of the screen during the boot process.  That's the way to access the advanced boot options in the Ubuntu DVD.
For more details on this go to the [Boot Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) page.

Comment: That has not been working either, any ideas as to why not? The keyboard works, I can get into bios and do things there.